# How to remove artifacts caused by sun beams node in compositor?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, antialiasing

The artifacts are like those of Aliasing.

Original Image:

[image]

With *Sun Beams* Node:

[image]

Using anti-aliasing node does not help.

[image]

Note that this is a zoomed-in view for better clarity and resolution.

Comment: Might just be a screen resolution limitation, look at it at 100% and see how it looks

Comment: @Ebi this is zoomed more than 200%. Rendered Image : https://i.imgur.com/L9sEZA5.png

Comment: 100% zoom will get rid of any screen artefacts and will let you see it as is – the 'real' pixels @CoolCoder

Comment: @Ebi you can see the rendered image. I was referring to the screenshots as more than 200%

Comment: what is your Render resolution?

Comment: @J.Doe 3840*2160

Comment: hmm .. can you share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/
I can reproduce it .. but ony with small render resolution.

Comment: Sure. But I am getting this error - https://i.imgur.com/WJZjo5v.png after clicking the Upload button

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AS_EH2dqeejNZNIHcbOc8B_Eobk25GIg/view google drive link.